# ImportError: No module named wx

Tags: python, wxpython

When I write "import wx" in the Python interpreter there is no problem, but when I run script with that line from Windows console, error "ImportError: No module named wx" appears.

Result of commands

```
help()
modules
```

contains

```
wx
wxPython
wxversion
```

sys.path contains

```
'<site-packages path>\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode'
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python used for the REPL is not the same as the Python the script is being run in. Print `sys.executable` to verify.

Comment: Thank you. Damn inattentiveness!